# Javascript: addEventListener not working in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, addeventlistener

SITUATION: I am getting a JSON array from an API. The "div" is from a getElementByID earlier in my code.

PROBLEM: the addEventListener only gets attached to the last element in my list.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < JSONarray.response.artists.length; i++){
      var artistName = JSONarray.response.artists[i];
      div.innerHTML += "<h4 id=\"artist" + i + "\" accessKey=\"" + artistName.id + "\">Artist Name: " +  artistName.name + "</h4>";
      document.getElementById("artist" + i).addEventListener("click", moreInfo, false);
    }
```

WEIRD THING: If I place the addEventListener in its own for-loop (with exact same loop script), it is perfectly happy and all my list items get their Listeners.

QUESTION: Is there a reason why I cannot put everything in one for-loop, or is it my code?

NOTE: I'm using Chrome to run this, if it happens to be a browser thing.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an anonymous function inline where you reference `moreInfo`?

Comment: If you do not need any special handling of the click event, simply use document.getElementById(...).onclick=moreInfo; or just inline as <... onclick="moreInfo('+i+')"

Comment: How is your `moreInfo` defined?

Comment: Oh, just was educated about the multiple replacement of innerHTML. never used event handlers on innerHTML anyway so never encountered the issue. Since discovering jQuery I would never use my own Jason handling. Have you considered jQuery which would simplify your handling immensely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying the innerHTML of the div each iteration for loop, thus causing all event handlers bound to some node that has that div as parent to be lost, as modifying the innerHTML causes all child nodes to be recreated from HTML.

Consider that `div.innerHTML += foo;` is really shorthand for `div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + foo;` and it should be apparent what I mean.

Edit: I realize my answer has already been accepted (as of April 8, 2013), but I still feel like I could have worded things a little better.

Think of `node.innerHTML = bar` as "replace everything that's a child of the node with whatever HTML can be interpreted from the string given (in `bar`)". It just so happens as part of the string given, you were giving the  HTML serialization of the node's former children via `node.innerHTML`.. so you are possibly loosing much more than just event handlers!

As you can see, this is not the best way to add html.

As a side note, supposing you do have to add a bunch of children to a node, *if the event  can bubble* (see [HTML DOM: Which events do not bubble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574207/javascript-which-events-do-not-bubble), or a more complete list on [Wikipedia's article on DOM events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events)), instead of adding a handler to each and every child node, you could also add a event handler to the *parent* node, and in modern browsers (IE9+), many events could be handled as they are *bubbled up*.  I haven't directly messed with event bubbling in the DOM as of late, but many third party libraries easily support this kind of event delegation. With jQuery, look at `jQuery.on`, and binding  declarations would work something like:

```
 jQuery(parentnodeselector).on(eventname,childselector)
```

AFAIK, it's not terribly hard to handle event bubbling on your own... you *would* need to be able to identify via `event.target` and `event.target`'s parents if the event bubbled up through the right children, though.

Comment: Now THAT is interesting info that I have never heard before. I had no idea that using innerHTML would throw off the eventhandlers. The little things that they do not tell/know.

Comment: @AsdAsd This sort of thing wouldn't happen if you didn't use `innerHTML` :)

Comment: @AsdAsd: yeah... even though I know you accepted my answer, I added a few more bits of info, just to clarify, and another event binding option you might not be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Inline event handlers, especially when created dynamically with `innerHTML` should not be encouraged. I even remember reading bad things about what happens in IE with this scenario. Try using something like this, which uses a more appropriate method for adding elements to the DOM:

```
for (var i = 0; i < JSONarray.response.artists.length; i++) {
    var artistName = JSONarray.response.artists[i];
    var newH4 = document.createElement("h4");
    newH4.id = "artist" + i;
    newH4.accessKey = artistName.id;    // You might have to use newH4.setAttribute("accessKey", artistName.id) instead
    newH4.innerHTML = "Artist Name: " +  artistName.name;
    newH4.addEventListener("click", moreInfo, false);
    div.appendChild(newH4);
}
```

If you care, older IE doesn't have `addEventListener` - so you'd need to check for `addEventListener`, and use `attachEvent` if it's not available. Just a warning. Something like:

```
if (newH4.addEventListener) {
    newH4.addEventListener("click", moreInfo, false);
} else if (newH4.attachEvent) {
    newH4.attachEvent("onclick", moreInfo);
} else {
    newH4.onclick = moreInfo;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't use `innerHTML` on the same element in a loop. It's more efficient to create one big string and append to that inside the for loop, then set `innerHTML` on the element **after** the loop. This gets considerably more important as the size of your `JSONarray.response.artists` array increases.

Comment: I would be curious to understand why exactly the original code is not working. I just tired it and it creates DOM elements successfully, with right IDs and `document.getElementByID` inside the loop finds them successfully, but yet only the last one gets the handler attached.

Comment: @akonsu True true, I guess my point is just that if you do things the "correct" way, you shouldn't have problems like this. Either way, it's interesting why it's being weird. Do you have a fiddle to test with?

Comment: here is one I created from @ArunPJohny's one: http://plnkr.co/edit/5Al4eo4ohQaoFS8IpdqE

Comment: @akonsu If you look at JayC's answer, that should explain **why** :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a dom update problem

```
for(var i = 0; i < JSONarray.response.artists.length; i++){
      var artistName = JSONarray.response.artists[i];
      div.innerHTML += '<h4 id="artist' + i + '" accessKey="' + artistName.id + '" onclick="moreInfo(this)">Artist Name: ' +  artistName.name + '</h4>';
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/1HCkj5ymUTPU8tIjSfTg?p=preview)

Comment: Slight syntax issue; escape the quotes around the `moreInfo()`