# Javascript: Global Element Focus Listener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a listener that listens for all focus events. In particular I am trying to listen for anytime an input or textbox gains focus. Per some research, the widely accepted way to achieve this is like this:

```
document.body.onfocus = function(event) {
   //Check the event.target for input/textbox
   //Do something
};
```

But the document.body.onfocus doesn't seem to fire, ever. I thought it might be because the document doesn't actually ever receive focus so I tried:

```
document.body.focus();
```

To initially "set" the focus, but this doesn't work either.

Any ideas on how I can listen to a focus event on all inputs/textboxes without actually setting the event directly on the element itself? Vanilla javascript only please, I am not using a framework.

Per the accepted answer here is some working code:

```
var focusHandler = function(event) {
    var type = event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if(type == 'input' || type == 'textarea') {
        //Do something
    }
};
document.body.addEventListener('focus', focusHandler, true); //Non-IE   
document.body.onfocusin = focusHandler; //IE
```

Comment: Where are you running this code? In the `<head>`? Or somewhere in the `<body>`? I don't think the `document.body` will be available when running code in the `<head>`...not sure though

Comment: A separate js file. Not in the html at all.

Comment: But where is the JS file being included in your HTML?

Comment: The body. I use document.body all the time for click events on the body so that is not the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574207/javascript-which-events-do-not-bubble - it doesn't bubble

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As some events (focus, blur, change) do not bubble up, I would recommend you to try `Event Capturing` instead. First of all `onfocus` will not work for this, so you have to use `addEventListener` where you are able to specifiy the used delegation mode in the third argument. Look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) for the use of `addEventListener`. 
And take a look at this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html) for further information about delegating the focus event up.

Comment: Works beautifully. Great article as well. I always wondered what that false at the end of an eventListener did! Updating OP with some working code.

Comment: This answer should include the relevant information behind these links, e.g. that event capturing is enabled with the third argument in `parentElement.addEventListener("focus", listener, true)` being `true`.

Answer (score 8):

The [`focus` event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-focus) doesn't bubble from elements up to their ancestor elements, so you can't use event delegation (hooking it on `body` and seeing it for all descendants of `body`) to detect it.

There's a newer event, [`focusin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-focusIn) (a Microsoft innovation, now also available in other browsers), which does bubble, so that may work for you depending on which browsers you want to support.

Comment: See this interesting article for further information and a nice hack: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html

Comment: And of course, if you're open to using libraries, jQuery makes `focus` and `blur` bubble in a cross-browser way without your having to worry about it.