# When support for bubbling `change` event from `input` to `form` is added?

Tags: html, forms, events

Based on [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574207/html-dom-which-events-do-not-bubble) it seems that in the past `change` event did not `bubble` from an `input` to the enclosing `form`, but currently it does in most web browsers. I'm curious to know from when support for bubbling change event was added, and if it can reliably be used?  I searched online and I wasn't able to find a reference.

Comment: Bubbling happens on the last event phase. Capturing phase goes from `form` down to the last node in the event chain (in a change event, it has to be an input, select, or textarea). Target phase is the `event.target` (e.g. input that's value has changed and is no longer in focus (blur)). Then bubbling phase is from the event.target back to the `form`.

Comment: @zer00ne Thanks, I updated my question to clear up my question.